# purrr map2(x,y, fun),but for each element of X, do all elements of y

Tags: r, purrr

From : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.2/topics/map2  we see that:

```
x <- list(1, 10, 100)
y <- list(1, 2, 3)
map2(x, y, ~ .x + .y)
```

generates

```
2, 12, 103
```

but what if what was required was:

```
2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13, 101, 102, 103
```

that is: for each `x[i]` add all members of `y[*]`

Seems simple to do for loops, but...  I am clearly missing something obvious in purrr.

Answer (score 10):

`map2` doesn't work here because it iterates in parallel across two lists/vectors, like `Map` or `mapply`. Instead, you're looking for `cross2`, which does a cross join of two lists. Three options:

```r
library(purrr)

x <- list(1, 10, 100)
y <- list(1, 2, 3)

cross2(y, x) %>% invoke_map_dbl(sum, .)
#> [1]   2   3   4  11  12  13 101 102 103

cross2(y, x) %>% map_dbl(~sum(unlist(.x)))
#> [1]   2   3   4  11  12  13 101 102 103

cross2(y, x) %>% simplify_all() %>% map_dbl(sum)
#> [1]   2   3   4  11  12  13 101 102 103
```

Another option if your lists are just numbers is `outer`:

```r
outer(unlist(x), unlist(y), `+`)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    2    3    4
#> [2,]   11   12   13
#> [3,]  101  102  103
```